# Caching ajax data in Javascript grid and UI controls

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, grid

I'm writing a rich UI in JS that needs to display large data sets returned from REST calls in a fluid layout, that will include many controls such as grids, tab strips, menus etc. Can you suggest some JS libs/toolkits that will let me do the following -

- intelligently cache the data, and fetch more as needed for the UI. The cache should be able to feed multiple UI controls and I want to use some sort of data-binding such as KnockoutJS. (The data will be returned from jQuery's ajaxManager).
- UI controls that detect when user is exceeding boundaries (such as scrolling in the grid) and automatically issue requests to cache to fetch more data. Some sort of jQuery plugin than can be used with a variety of widgets would be preferable.
- which grid control is easiest to use with the following requirements: must be data driven (all data comes from json/objects from cache, all html is from jquery templates), need not be editable, layout has to be flexible, support cells of different sizes. Basically I'm looking for a combination if isotope's layout engine with SlickGrids virtual rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Sencha's Ext-JS](http://www.sencha.com/).  It has all of those things!

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it - do you have any specifics besides their Grid? I don't see any ajax/data caching. Already invested in jQuery (probably should have mentioned that) and I'd prefer using that.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I don't know all the details of jQuery, but Ext can live side by side with jQuery.  Here is a page full of Ext demos.  http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/

Comment: Also note, they have an "infinite" grid which you'll notice caches the data client side, and adds/removes items from the DOM to keep performance up.